# Rebuild JavaScript file which uses Ruby constant via Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

How can I force Heroku to rebuild a JavaScript file which uses a Ruby constant via the Asset Pipeline's chained extension feature (e.g. my-file.js.coffee.erb) without changing the file and re-deploying?

I've changed the Heroku environment variable and run `heroku run rake assets:precompile`, but the file is still not using the updated constant. (The constant is set in an initializer using said env var.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
$ heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Purge cache"
$ git push heroku master
```

Where **appname** is replaced by the name of the app you want to clear the cache for.